# how to write code to consume large piece of real memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management

For testing purposes, should use over 90% "real" memory not "virtual".
Not expert at all, just use malloc to declare large piece.
But that goes to virtual. 
Then constantly random read/write into different locations, still only around 1%.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What platform? Linux? Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways :

[Memory Allocation Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3520/Memory-Allocation-Tool)

[Memory Cache .Net 4.0 performance test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729023/memory-cache-net-4-0-performance-test-astonishing-result)